# Determinant of Block Tridiagonal Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, recursion, block-matrices

I found in the following paper: 
  [Comments on ‘‘A note on a three-term recurrence
for a tridiagonal matrix’’](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0096300305008209/1-s2.0-S0096300305008209-main.pdf?_tid=7bc0b068-fbd4-11e7-be54-00000aab0f01&acdnat=1516227748_6a0e62a203a0e6edec8ced87c51ddf63) that we can compute the determinant of a block tridiagonal matrix **A** via a recursion.

In my particular case **A** is $4n\times4n$,

$$\textbf{A}=\begin{pmatrix}
\textbf{B}_L-h\textbf{R} & J\space\textbf{R} & \textbf{0} & \cdots & \textbf{0} \\
J\space \textbf{R} & -h\textbf{R} & J\space\textbf{R} &  & \textbf{0} \\
\textbf{0} & J\space \textbf{R} & -h\textbf{R} &\ddots &\vdots \\
\vdots &  &\ddots &\ddots & J\space\textbf{R}\\
\textbf{0} & \textbf{0} & \cdots & J \space\textbf{R} & \textbf{B}_R-h\textbf{R}
\end{pmatrix}$$

where 
$$\textbf{R}=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
-1&0&0&0\\
0&-1&0&0\\ 
\end{pmatrix},\space
\textbf{B}_{L,R}=\begin{pmatrix}
0&\frac{i}{2}\Gamma_{+}^{\text{L,R}}&-\frac{i}{2}\Gamma_{-}^{\text{L,R}}&\frac{1}{2}\Gamma_{-}^{\text{L,R}}\\
-\frac{i}{2}\Gamma_{+}^{\text{L,R}}&0&\frac{1}{2}\Gamma_{-}^{\text{L,R}}&\frac{i}{2}\Gamma_{-}^{\text{L,R}}\\
\frac{i}{2}\Gamma_{-}^{\text{L,R}}&-\frac{1}{2}\Gamma_{-}^{\text{L,R}}&0&\frac{i}{2}\Gamma_{+}^{\text{L,R}}\\
-\frac{1}{2}\Gamma_{-}^{\text{L,R}}&-\frac{i}{2}\Gamma_{-}^{\text{L,R}}&-\frac{i}{2}\Gamma_{+}^{\text{L,R}}&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $$J,h,\Gamma_{+}^{\text{L,R}},\Gamma_{-}^{\text{L,R}} \in \mathbb{R}$$

Now let me state the recursion mentioned in the above paper,

$$\text{det}(\textbf{A})=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\text{det}(\Lambda_{k})\space\space\space\space(1)$$

where (in my case),

$$
\Lambda_{1} = \textbf{B}_L-h\textbf{R}\\
\Lambda_{k} = -h\textbf{R}-J^{2}\textbf{R}\Lambda_{k-1}^{-1}\textbf{R}\\
\Lambda_{n}=\textbf{B}_R-h\textbf{R}-J^{2}\textbf{R}\Lambda_{n-1}^{-1}\textbf{R}
$$ 
Now according to (1), the set of eigenvalues of $\textbf{A}$ should contain the eigenvalues of $\Lambda_{1} = \textbf{B}_L-h\textbf{R}$ since applying (1) to $\textbf{A}-\lambda I_{4n}$ gives $\Lambda_{1}^{'} = \textbf{B}_L-h\textbf{R}-\lambda I_{4}$.

**Now here comes my issue**.

I computed the spectrum of **A** in Mathematica for $n=50$ for the values $h=1,J=1.5,\Gamma_{+}^{\text{L}}=1.6,\Gamma_{+}^{\text{R}}=1.3,\Gamma_{-}^{\text{L}}=-0.4,\Gamma_{-}^{\text{R}}=-0.7$

I found that the spectrum did not contain the eigenvalues of $\textbf{B}_{L}-h\textbf{R}$. My question is: Is this recursion not applicable to my case, or am I incorrect in stating that the set of eigenvalues of  **A** should contain the eigenvalues of $\Lambda_{1}$?

Comment: From the dimensional argument, I suspect that the upper bound for k in (1) is n, not 4n (this doesn't solve the question, but is a prerequisit for further actions). Also, the second $I_{4n}$ is probably $I_4$.

Comment: From what dimensional argument? **A** is 4nx4n. Also I made the appropriate change to the identity

Comment: $\det(\Lambda_k)$ is a 4th degree homogeneous function of the elements of **A**. det(**A**) is a 4n-th degree homogeneous function of the elements of **A**. So det(**A**) can be a product of n $\det(\Lambda_k)$'s, but not 4n.

Comment: ah, yes. i shall make the change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursion in the paper is a generalization of the classical determinant relation for block matrices (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices)): if $A$ is invertible then
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}A & B\\C & D\end{bmatrix}=\det A\cdot\det(D-CA^{-1}B).
$$
The block matrix does not share eigenvalues with the $A$ block in general, since $\lambda I-A$ becomes not invertible for an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, hence, the formula cannot be applied.

Edit: there is an alternative formula for evaluation of the determinant of a tridiagonal matrix [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.702.6931&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (look Theorem 2). It uses only inversions of off-diagonal blocks that do not contain $\lambda$ in your case.

Comment: What if I computed when $\text{det}(\Lambda_{n}^{'})=0$?(where by adding the prime I mean take $h\textbf{R}-\lambda\text{I}_{4}, \textbf{B}_{R}-h\textbf{R}-\lambda\text{I}_{4}, \textbf{B}_{L}-h\textbf{R}-\lambda\text{I}_{4}$)  Shouldn't the solutions to that equation give eigenvalues of $\textbf{A}$?

Comment: @user1058860 If you calculate with polynomials in $\lambda$ then you will get a rational function with lots of cancellations. If you manage to cancel everything you should get a polynomial, which is the characteristic polynomial of $A$ (in your notation). But it is almost an impossible task numerically due to round off errors. Maybe symbolically for some relatively low dimensions is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Second. Indeed, $\Lambda'_2$ is already not a polynomial in $\lambda$; moreover, it becomes undefined when $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $\Lambda_1$.