# Analytical expression for the determinant of block tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, block-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

I have a $3n\times3n$ matrix $M$ that is in the following block tridiagonal form:
$$M=\begin{pmatrix} 
A & B^T & 0\\
B & A & UBU \\
0 & UB^T U & A\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
where $A,B,U$ are $n\times n$ real matrices. I also know that $A$ and $U$ are **symmetric** and $U$ is **orthogonal** (it is *the exchange matrix*), and that $\det{B} = 0$. I want to know if a closed-form analytical expression for the determinant of $M$ exists.

What I have tried so far:
From the paper mentioned in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2609826/determinant-of-block-tridiagonal-matrix), I found that one can write
$$\det{M} = \det{\Lambda_1}\det{\Lambda_2}\det{\Lambda_3},$$ with $\Lambda_1 = A$, $\Lambda_2 = A - B \Lambda_1^{-1} B^T$, and $\Lambda_3 = A - (UB^TU)\Lambda_2^{-1}(UBU)$.

I have not been able to progress beyond this point as I do not know of some clever way to do *the inversions*. 

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If A is invertible then by the determinant of a block matrix, $\det(M)=\det(A)\det(A)\det(A-B^TA^{-1}B-UB^TUA^{-1}UBU)$

Comment: Tip: Use `\det`.