# Localization of eigenvalues for block-tridiagonal Hermitian Toeplitz matrix made of gamma blocks

Tags: reference-request, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, kronecker-product, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

I am studying the spectrum of a particular kind of block-tridiagonal Hermitian Toeplitz matrix made of three bands $\{B,A,C\}$

$$ T_n = \begin{pmatrix}
      A & C & 0 & \dots & 0\\
      B & A & C & \vdots & \vdots\\
      0 & B & \ddots  & \ddots & \vdots\\
      \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & A & C\\
      0 & \dots & \dots & B & A
      \end{pmatrix} $$

where each block is constructed with gamma matrices $\Gamma_{ij} = \sigma_i \otimes \sigma_j$ (Kronecker products of Pauli matrices) in the following way :

$$ A=\Gamma_{22},B=\Gamma_{22}-i\Gamma_{03},C=\Gamma_{22}+i\Gamma_{03} $$

Such kind of matrix has determinant 1 and I notice its spectrum has interesting localization property. In particular, there are only 4 eigenvalues in the range $(-1,1)$ no matter what value $n$ is. As $n$ increase, there are more eigenvalues with absolute value bigger than $1$ and thus the four degenerate eigenvalues are forced to tend to zero as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Moreover, this pattern is observed if $\Gamma_{22}$ and $\Gamma_{03}$ are replaced by any pair of anticommuting real Hermitian gamma matrices.

Is there any reference for these interesting spectral properties?

Comment: When you mention "gamma matrices" (a non-standard term) that you denote $\Gamma_{ij} = \sigma_i \otimes \sigma_j$ what do you mean 1) by this symbol $\otimes$ : Kronecker product ? 2) by symbol $\sigma_i$ (which is not standard, unless these are Pauli matrices) ? Could you give some details ?

Comment: @Jean Marie Yes, they mean Kronecker product and Pauli matrices respectively.

Comment: Could you confirm that you take the same indexing convention of the $\sigma_i$'s as [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) with $\sigma_0$ = identity ?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm.

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2609826/305862